# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT bug. why my queries with GROUP_concat not work

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT CONCAT(`date`,',',`viewcount`) 
FROM `stat` 
WHERE `stat`.`id` = 1 
  AND `channelstat`.`date` BETWEEN (SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)) AND NOW()
```

This query work well and gave me result of last 2 days in CSV kind of format.

I think to generate whole csv file in MySQL. I tried to write my command to do it. When I tried GROUP_CONCAT it's not work well. Now I got rows from date less then 4 August. I am amazed because first queries make it from less then today.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`date`,',',`viewcount`) SEPARATOR '\r\n') 
FROM `stat` 
WHERE `stat`.`id` = 1 
  AND `stat`.`date` BETWEEN (SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 90 DAY)) AND NOW()
```

in second queries the last 2 line are which is totally invalid

```
2013-08-04,798
2013-08-
```

Somebody please tell me why it's not work. Why last line is different when rows are available from today to last 4 months.

The second queries have bugs like

> invalid group concat or I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your result gets truncated by GROUP_CONCAT.

As the documentation for [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) says:

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet. The syntax to change the value of group_concat_max_len at runtime is as follows, where val is an unsigned integer:

```
SET [GLOBAL | SESSION] group_concat_max_len = val;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```
$res=$mysqli->query("SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(client_id) as clients FROM services WHERE id = 3 GROUP BY id");
$row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result = explode(',', $row['clients']); // $row['clients'] contains string 5,6,7
$res->free();
```